# Unable to locate element with xpath using python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Hi I am trying access an element in selenium that looks like this when I inspect element:

```
<div class="im_message_outer_wrap hasselect" ng-click="toggleMessage(historyMessage.mid, $event)" data-msg-id="5973">
```

I have tried to find element using its xpath as follows:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class = 'im_message_outer_wrap hasselect'][@data-msg-id='5967']")
```

This keeps returning an error saying unable to locate element. What am i doing wrong or is there a better way to access this element. The data-msg-ID is important because in the code I want to be able to iterate through ids to grab each element in order.

Answer (score -1):

To locate the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.im_message_outer_wrap.hasselect[ng-click^='toggleMessage']")
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='im_message_outer_wrap hasselect' and starts-with(@ng-click, 'toggleMessage')]")
  ```

---

Ideally, to locate the **clickable** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.im_message_outer_wrap.hasselect[ng-click^='toggleMessage']")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='im_message_outer_wrap hasselect' and starts-with(@ng-click, 'toggleMessage')]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```